# 9 bit protocol on UART in embedded Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, uart, parity

I am trying to force a 9-bit protocol on a UART in embedded Linux.  Currently I am testing this out on the am335x_evm board.  I am planning on doing this using stick parity.  Ideally I was hoping I would not need to actually modify any of the code for the omap-serial.c driver.

The reason for the 9-bit protocol is to support some legacy hardware that uses it.  The parity bit needs to be 1 for the address portion of the message, 0 for the data portion, then 1 again for the termination byte.

I was planning on having a process running in user space that would interface with the UART through standard system calls (open, write, read, ioctl, tcsetattr, etc).  I would configure the UART to enable parity and set the stick parity.  I would then set the parity to even and call write() to send out my address data.  I would then set the parity to 0 and send out the data.  My concern is if I change the parity from 1 to 0, when does that take affect?  If the UART is not done sending all the address data, will the change in parity apply to any unsent data?

Comment: That's a very good questions. You can always flush the channel, but that introduces a slight delay between your address and data, which may not be understood by your peripherals.

Comment: The flush may not be a bad idea.  I will keep that one in mind. You are correct about the delay though.  The receivers of the message will only wait a short period before discarding what they have.

Comment: Another option is to write your own serial `line discipline` driver. It's not the easiest thing in the world, but not the hardest either. That allows you to send messages to/from user space via ioctl (and possible read/write) one message at a time, as opposed to byte stream. Then discipline driver has more access from kernel space. This approach will also help you in *receiving* messages a lot.

Comment: Something like that was going to be my fallback option.  To use ioctl to send what I needed into the uart driver then at that lower level I would have more control.

Comment: @qarma - *"write your own serial line discipline driver...(and) send messages to/from user space via ioctl"* --  If you use a line discipline, then abusing the **ioctl()** won't work because it bypasses the line discipline.

Comment: Without a UART that is 9-bit capable, you could come up with a scheme to transmit 8 bits of data plus a forced 0 or 1 parity as the 9th data bit.  But receiving is much more difficult, will require driver modifications, require programmed I/O (i.e. no DMA) and require transmission to be suspended while receiving.  Simplified description is at http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/3BDC7FF03541F772862564990057F919.

Comment: @sawdust common ioctls may be handled by tty layer, but custom ioctls are possible, here's an example http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/n_r3964.c#L1183 (example only, that module that code is old, broken and outright horrible, rather use another n_xxx.c)

Answer (score 2):

Ended up writing my own 9-bit uart driver.  Was the easiest and most efficient solution.

Comment: Can you share the source with the community, please? I want to use 9-bit uart too, and it seems there are many people around the world too!

Comment: Yea, same here.  That would be awesome

Comment: I'm very curious as well to see this, I've been attempting this and I've gotten Tx figured out I believe but Rx seems to be much more difficult or I'm overlooking something trivial... any guidance would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Proper way is to set `cs9` on your serial port (and possibly no parity), provided that hardware and driver support this.

I'll search for a link for you...

Comment: Thank you, however the UARTs on the TI Sitara chip (the one on the avm335X_evm) do not support CS9.  Hence why I am trying to go the stick parity route.